# evolution error in ubuntu :The reported error was Could not connect to imap.gmail.com:993: TCP connection reset by peer

Tags: evolution

I am trying to send and receive mail on Evolution but again and again I get this message :

```
Could not connect to imap.gmail.com:993: TCP connection reset by peer
```

I enabled imap in gmail but still Evolution is showing this error.I need help.